# Find() on a non-object?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I am trying to access the `find()` on another model in a controller.  I am getting a

**Call to a member function find() on a non-object** error

`PollsController.php` (controller):

```
class PollsController extends AppController{
    public function add(){
        $this->set('appNames', $this->App->find('list'));
    }
}
```

`Poll.php` (model):

```
class Poll extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo = array ('App');
}
```

`App.php` (model):

```
class App extends AppModel{
    public $hasMany = array('Poll');
}
```

Note: I have also tried `$this->Poll->App->find('list')` and still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**App is reserved keyword.**  When I change the class to SomethingController.php and Something.php, everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access another model functions you need load model. There is few ways to do it.

This one is only useful for controllers

```
$this->loadModel('App');
$this->App->find('first');
```

This one is good for models and controllers

Read more: [CakeAPI: Class ClassRegistry](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-ClassRegistry.html)

```
$appModel = ClassRegistry::init('App');
$appModel->find('first');
```

This one is good for controllers

Read more: [CakeAPI: $uses variable in controller](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Controller.html#%24uses)

```
//in Post Controller
public $use=array('Post','App');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please load modal in your controller

public $uses = array("Poll");